# npm start error while running application

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node and npm currently in learning phase. I was able to run the server and npm start before but after I uploaded some folders in my project directory npm start did not work and is giving several errors. I need help in understanding what do I need to fix in my project.

```
    > workspace@1.0.0 start /home/ubuntu/workspace/nodeproject
> node app.js

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/home/ubuntu/workspace/nodeproject/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/nodeproject/app.js:14:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)

npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-c9
npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.5.0/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.5.0/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! workspace@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the workspace@1.0.0 start script 'node app.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the workspace package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node app.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs workspace
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls workspace
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/nodeproject/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: You are already using port `8080` in another application. You may like to change port and then run

Comment: @ArifKhan Do you know how can I change port I am new to node and can't seem to find that. Should I make changes in app.js file or some other directory do you know?

Comment: try to run `export PORT=8081 && npm start` and then use `8081` in the place of `8080` or you may use another port like `3000` and if still not working then post your `app.js` code in your question so that we can help you where you need to modify

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem of npm itself.

You are already using port `8080`, try change it to e.g.

```
server.listen(8081)
```

If you're on osx, try to change your start script from package.json to

```
env PORT=8081 node app.js
```

because your code depends on it.

On the other hand you can set it by hands

```
var port = 8081
app.listen(port, function(err){ console.log('The server is running on port: '+ port); });
```

Comment: I am not sure what to fix in my app.js file can you refer it in my code it will be great

Comment: var express = require("express");
    var app = express();

    var port = process.env.PORT;

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Aloha world!');
    });

    app.get('/routing', function(req, res){
    res.send('Aloha Routing!');
    });

   app.listen(port, function(err){
    console.log('The server is running on port: '+ port);
   });

Answer (score 0):

You may pass port during running command as following

```
export PORT=3000 && npm start
```

you may use other than `3000` port as well **or** you may like to change inside code as following

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT | 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Aloha world!');
});
app.get('/routing', function(req, res){
  res.send('Aloha Routing!');
});

app.listen(port, function(err){
  console.log('The server is running on port: '+ port);
});
```

I have just updated `var port = process.env.PORT | 3000;` in your code

Now you may browse http://localhost:3000 or http://localhost:3000/routing

I hope this help you :)

Comment: Still npm is not running but I am getting this error below

Comment: ` npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.5.0/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.5.0/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! path /home/ubuntu/workspace/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ubuntu/workspace/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/npm-debug.log`

Comment: @havenchyk Can you help me with the above error maybe.

Comment: @bmalhi what is your main file name and directory structure? If you are using `app.js` then use this command `export PORT=3000 && node /home/ubuntu/workspace/app.js`

Comment: @bmalhi it looks like something wrong with your package.json or you're running command from the wrong location in console